# Flutter firebase auth works fine and registers the users but after that the app just quits instead of navigating to a new screen.The app just stops

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

As the user clicks the button he gets registered using firebase (create user) .After that the just stops and quits and does not navigate to an another page.The app stops in the debug and quits the debug mode.

i tried flutter clean and reinstalled the app on my phone and it worked. I am able to see the registered users in firestore but after authentication the app just quits.

It's not navigating to a new page -

```
onPressed: () async { try{ final newuser = await 
_auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email,password: password); 
if(newuser!=null){ Navigator.pushNamed(context, ChatScreen.id); } } 
catch(e){ print(e); }
```

I think the error is this  - E/JavaBinder(13980): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;

the output is this
      iChannelGoogleApi(13980): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() 
       returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@2e2943
    E  /JavaBinder(13980): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not 
     yet supported across processes.)
E/JavaBinder(13980): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzc(Unknown Source:22)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzde(Unknown Source:17)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzdd(Unknown Source:8)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzan.zzdf(Unknown Source:1)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.isAnonymous(Unknown Source:47)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzi(Unknown Source:57)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzg(Unknown Source:10)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source:62)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$zzb.zza(Unknown Source:5)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzax.zzdx(Unknown Source:15)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zzen(Unknown Source:35)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zza(Unknown Source:41)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzep.zza(Unknown Source:9)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:9)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source:13)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)
E/JavaBinder(13980): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.flashchat-TZhJVKnl0Lsx4l6grV97yQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.flashchat-TZhJVKnl0Lsx4l6grV97yQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.flashchat-TZhJVKnl0Lsx4l6grV97yQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/JavaBinder(13980):    ... 16 more
E/AndroidRuntime(13980): FATAL EXCEPTION: Binder:13980_4
E/AndroidRuntime(13980): Process: com.example.flashchat, PID: 13980
E/AndroidRuntime(13980): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzc(Unknown Source:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzde(Unknown Source:17)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzdd(Unknown Source:8)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzan.zzdf(Unknown Source:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.isAnonymous(Unknown Source:47)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzi(Unknown Source:57)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzg(Unknown Source:10)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source:62)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$zzb.zza(Unknown Source:5)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzax.zzdx(Unknown Source:15)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zzen(Unknown Source:35)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zza(Unknown Source:41)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzep.zza(Unknown Source:9)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:9)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source:13)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.flashchat-TZhJVKnl0Lsx4l6grV97yQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.flashchat-TZhJVKnl0Lsx4l6grV97yQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.flashchat-TZhJVKnl0Lsx4l6grV97yQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(13980):        ... 16 more
Lost connection to device.
D/ViewRootImpl@3554d48MainActivity: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager(13980): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@7f76e56[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager(13980): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
I/Process (13980): Sending signal. PID: 13980 SIG: 9

E/JavaBinder(13980): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the `ChatScreen.id` is the route name.

Try to Navigate like this

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChatScreen()),
);
```

If it works check again how to use the named route for navigation.

What's the error in your debug console?